# Change application's name

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I change the application's name without changing it's bundle identifier?
I've tried changing the bundle identifier in the .plist file so it will remain the same, but when trying to run the application i get an error in xcode stating:

```
No such file or directory (/Users/myUserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OLD_APPLICATION_NAME-hhknzcpmarwfwldirezkiexvenqp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NEW_APPLICATION_NAME.app/NEW_APPLICATION_NAME)
```

This only happends when running on device. On simulator it works fine.

Found answer to my own question. See answer below as I can't accept it for another couple of days.

So I had to change the app's name after having changed the provisioning profile to one that didn't match my application's name. 
So I only needed to change the name of the application that's being displayed on the device home-screen.
This can be done by only changing the Bundle Display Name, found in the .plist file. Thanks for your quick responses anyway.

Comment: did you try deleting the app and staring again? Or cleaning the project

Comment: @Anne there's very little reason to ever need to rename an Xcode project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should change the `CFBundleDisplayName` in the apps Info plist file. This value is what the iOS spring board uses underneath each app. This can also be localised.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it was the first one, although I also found the answer on my own but a minute later.

Answer (score -1):

Change the bundle name `.bundle` identifier is for the **provisioning profile**.